# How to duplicate 4 time values of a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Microsoft Excel and I have a column with number :

```
1
0
6
.
.
.
0
```

and I'd like to duplicate 4 time each value in a new column :

```
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
6
6
6
6
.
.
.
0
0
0
0
```

Is there a function to do so?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your first column is A, you can duplicate the values four times using something like the follwoing filled down column B:

```
=INDIRECT("A"& CEILING(ROW()/4,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works well. There is a little mistake, it's `;`instead of `,`. In my case, I am using Excel in french so the `ROW()`and `CEILING()` functions don't work. It's respectively `LIGNE()` and `PLAFOND()`.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. The comma vs semicolon separators are locale specific in addition to the function names.